# How to fix 'TableModel.setValueAt ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' error in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable application. I need to change the cell values and save the data, but only cells with index smaller than or equal to 4 are within the array bounds.

```
package fi.allu.neliojuuri;

import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Neliojuuri extends JPanel
    implements ActionListener, ItemListener, TableModelListener {

String newline = "\n";
private JTable table;
private JCheckBox rowCheck;
private JCheckBox columnCheck;
private JCheckBox cellCheck;
private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
private JTextArea output;

private String[] sarakenimet = new String[70];
private String[] sisakkainen = new String[70];
private Object[][] ulkoinen = new String[71][71];

private DefaultTableModel oletusmalli = null;
private CellEditorListener solumuokkaaja = null;

public Neliojuuri() {
    super();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));        

    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
            sarakenimet[i] = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sisakkainen.length; i++) {
            sisakkainen[i] = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ulkoinen.length; i++) {
            ulkoinen[i] = sisakkainen;
        }

    table = new JTable(ulkoinen, sarakenimet);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 210));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setRowHeight(30);

    TableColumnModel sarakeMalli = table.getColumnModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        sarakeMalli.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(75);
    }

    oletusmalli = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(oletusmalli);

    String[] sarakenimet = new String[70];
    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        sarakenimet[i] = String.valueOf(i + 1);
    }

    String[] sisakkainen = new String[70];
    for (int i = 0; i < sisakkainen.length; i++) {
        sisakkainen[i] = String.valueOf(i + 1);
    }
    Object[][] ulkoinen = new String[71][71];
    for (int i = 0; i < ulkoinen.length; i++) {
        ulkoinen[i] = sisakkainen;
    }

    oletusmalli.setColumnIdentifiers(sarakenimet);

    for (int count = 0; count < 70; count++){
        oletusmalli.insertRow(count, sisakkainen);
    }

    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowListener());
    table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().
            addListSelectionListener(new ColumnListener());
    add(new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);

    add(new JLabel("Selection Mode"));
    buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    addRadio("Multiple Interval Selection").setSelected(true);
    addRadio("Single Selection");
    addRadio("Single Interval Selection");

    add(new JLabel("Selection Options"));
    rowCheck = addCheckBox("Row Selection");
    rowCheck.setSelected(true);
    columnCheck = addCheckBox("Column Selection");
    cellCheck = addCheckBox("Cell Selection");
    cellCheck.setEnabled(false);

    output = new JTextArea(5, 40);
    output.setEditable(false);
    output.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    add(new JScrollPane(output));
}

private JCheckBox addCheckBox(String text) {
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(text);
    checkBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(checkBox);
    return checkBox;
}

private JRadioButton addRadio(String text) {
    JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton(text);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    buttonGroup.add(b);
    add(b);
    return b;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    JFileChooser tiedostovalitsin = new JFileChooser();        

    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    if (source.getText() == "Save") {
        int palautusArvo = tiedostovalitsin.showSaveDialog(Neliojuuri.this);

        if (palautusArvo == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File tiedosto = tiedostovalitsin.getSelectedFile();
            // Tallenna tiedosto oikeasti
            for (int i = 0; i < oletusmalli.getRowCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(oletusmalli.getValueAt(1, i).toString());
            }
            System.out.println(tiedosto.getName());
        }
    }

    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    //Cell selection is disabled in Multiple Interval Selection
    //mode. The enabled state of cellCheck is a convenient flag
    //for this status.
    if ("Row Selection" == command) {
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(rowCheck.isSelected());
        //In MIS mode, column selection allowed must be the
        //opposite of row selection allowed.
        if (!cellCheck.isEnabled()) {
            table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(!rowCheck.isSelected());
        }
    } else if ("Column Selection" == command) {
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(columnCheck.isSelected());
        //In MIS mode, row selection allowed must be the
        //opposite of column selection allowed.
        if (!cellCheck.isEnabled()) {
            table.setRowSelectionAllowed(!columnCheck.isSelected());
        }
    } else if ("Cell Selection" == command) {
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(cellCheck.isSelected());
    } else if ("Multiple Interval Selection" == command) {
        table.setSelectionMode(
                ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        //If cell selection is on, turn it off.
        if (cellCheck.isSelected()) {
            cellCheck.setSelected(false);
            table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        }
        //And don't let it be turned back on.
        cellCheck.setEnabled(false);
    } else if ("Single Interval Selection" == command) {
        table.setSelectionMode(
                ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        //Cell selection is ok in this mode.
        cellCheck.setEnabled(true);
    } else if ("Single Selection" == command) {
        table.setSelectionMode(
                ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //Cell selection is ok in this mode.
        cellCheck.setEnabled(true);
    }

    //Update checkboxes to reflect selection mode side effects.
    rowCheck.setSelected(table.getRowSelectionAllowed());
    columnCheck.setSelected(table.getColumnSelectionAllowed());
    if (cellCheck.isEnabled()) {
        cellCheck.setSelected(table.getCellSelectionEnabled());
    }
}

private void outputSelection() {
    output.append(String.format("Lead: %d, %d. ",
            table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex(),
            table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().
                    getLeadSelectionIndex()));
    output.append("Rows:");
    for (int c : table.getSelectedRows()) {
        output.append(String.format(" %d", c));
    }
    output.append(". Columns:");
    for (int c : table.getSelectedColumns()) {
        output.append(String.format(" %d", c));
    }
    output.append(".\n");
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int rivi = e.getFirstRow();
    int sarake = e.getColumn();
    TableModel malli = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    String sarakeNimi = malli.getColumnName(sarake);
    Object data = malli.getValueAt(rivi, sarake);
    MyTableModel taulumalli = new MyTableModel();
    taulumalli.setValueAt(data, rivi, sarake);
    System.out.println("rivi: " + rivi + " sarake: " + sarake + " data: " + data);
}

private void setValueAt(Object data, int rivi, int sarake) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

private class RowListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            return;
        }
        output.append("ROW SELECTION EVENT. ");
        outputSelection();
    }
}

private class ColumnListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            return;
        }
        output.append("COLUMN SELECTION EVENT. ");
        outputSelection();
    }
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
        "Last Name",
        "Sport",
        "# of Years",
        "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
            "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
            "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
            "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
            "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
            "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * editable.
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

}

public JMenuBar luoValikkoPalkki() {
    JMenuBar valikkopalkki = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu valikko = new JMenu("File");
    valikko.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    valikko.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "File saving menu");
    valikkopalkki.add(valikko);

    JMenuItem valikkoitem = new JMenuItem("Save", KeyEvent.VK_S);
    valikkoitem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    valikkoitem.addActionListener(this);
    valikko.add(valikkoitem);
    return valikkopalkki;
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
 * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Disable boldface controls.
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Neliöjuuri");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Neliojuuri neliojuuri = new Neliojuuri();
    frame.setJMenuBar(neliojuuri.luoValikkoPalkki());

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    Neliojuuri newContentPane = new Neliojuuri();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at fi.allu.neliojuuri.Neliojuuri$MyTableModel.setValueAt(Neliojuuri.java:356)
at fi.allu.neliojuuri.Neliojuuri.tableChanged(Neliojuuri.java:261)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:666)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2744)
at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4729)
at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:233)
at javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor.stopCellEditing(JTable.java:5473)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.actionPerformed(DefaultCellEditor.java:385)
at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1668)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I expect to be able to change all the cell values in the table, but I can only do so to a few of them. Cells with index greater than or equal to 5 return ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When execution reaches line `taulumalli.setValueAt(data, rivi, sarake);` inside `tableChanged()`, there are 2 table models.

First table model is created by the line `table = new JTable(ulkoinen, sarakenimet);`. This model is actually connected to the table displayed. It has 70 rows and 70 columns.

Second table model is created inside `tableChanged()` by the line `MyTableModel taulumalli = new MyTableModel();`. Even though this is a table model, it is not connected to any table. This has 5 rows and 5 columns.

When user edit a value in the table, `tableChanged()` is invoked. Inside this method, in the first 2 lines, row index and column index you get is from the first table model (because the displayed table is connected to this table model). Then you pass these row index and column index of the first table model to `setValueAt()` of the second table model. Which is incorrect because the 2 table models have different structures. This cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Cells with index greater than or equal to 5 return ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error.

Because you create your "MyTableModel" which only 5 rows of data. You can only change the data if the row/column exists in the model.

Why would you be using the "MyTableModel" from the Swing tutorial as your TableModel?

Also, why would you create a new "MyTableModel" every time the "tableChanged" event is generated? This means you will lose previous changes.

I would suggest if you are trying to copy data from one table to another, then you need to create a `DefaultTableModel`, with the same number of row/columns as exist in your other TableModel that generated the "tableChanged" event.

But without knowing your real requirement, we can't give a proper solution, only eliminate the error.